# how to clean data on HBase?

Tags: hbase

I have huge data on HBase and I found some row have invalid value, so I need to delete these data. Write a script to scan the whole table seem like 
a little bit low efficiency, have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can load the data to hive, then clean the data , and load it back to hbase.